# qqplot+geom_bar() -- Summary bar/facet of a column

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I haven't been found any solution to the following problem.

My data.frame looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5),c("A","A","B","A","B"),
                     c("known","unknown","unknown","known","known")))  
colnames(df)<- c("id","class","type") 
df  
id class    type  
1  1     A   known  
2  2     A unknown  
3  3     B unknown  
4  4     A   known  
5  5     B   known
```

And I use qplot to create a histogram of the types:

```
qplot(class,data=df,facets=.~type)
```

Additionally I'm looking for an option to add one "summary bar" and one "summary facet", to get an overview of all known, all unknown  and the number of A,B,A&B in all(known and unknown) types.

I tried it with `ggplot()+geom_bar()`, but I failed, too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but anyway, try `qplot(class,data=df) + facet_grid(.~type, margin=TRUE)`.

Comment: Yes it is, thank you. Additionally I want one bar "A&B" for all three pics. Is this possible, too?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your desired result is to create multiple plots (using ggplot) and then to arrange them as you like. The package gridExtra does this nicely.

```
library(gridExtra)

#create the separate graphs you desire
all_types <- ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x=class)) + ggtitle("All Types")
all_classes<- ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x=type)) + ggtitle("All Classes A & B") 
facets <- ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x=class)) + facet_grid(.~type) + ggtitle("Facet by Type")

#Now plot it all together
grid.arrange(all_types, all_classes, facets, ncol=2)
```

Which yields:
[image]